# How to Share Image + Text together using ACTION_SEND in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, android-sharing

I want to share Text + Image together using ACTION_SEND in android, I am using below code, I can share only Image but i can not share Text with it,

```
private Uri imageUri;
private Intent intent;

imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName()+ "/drawable/" + "ic_launcher");
intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Any help on this ?

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2222703   'MMS' is separate protocol for sending text/image messages. Not great because it has lots of carrier imposed limits. You may want to check it out.

Comment: Did you fixed this issue? if fixed means share you idea.

Answer (score 71):

You can share plain text with the following code

```
String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.share_using)));
```

So your full code (your image + text) becomes

```
private Uri imageUri;
private Intent intent;
    
imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +
    "/drawable/" + "ic_launcher");

intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
// text
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello");
//image
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
//type of content
intent.setType("*/*");
//sending
startActivity(intent);
```

I just replaced `image/*` with `*/*`

**Update**:

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +
    "/drawable/" + "ic_launcher");
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "send"));
```

Comment: put setType before first putExtra and retry.

Comment: umm, try to share/send it to another app

Comment: i tried to gamil, whatsapp and viber, among of them gmail and viber crashed :(

Comment: its not working, image not sharing to fb, for other(twitter,gmail) its working

Comment: cuz fb needs its own implementation way, you need to use its sdk.

Comment: Working with Whatsapp, Gmail and many other applications, Thanks. I badly needed this FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION. Thanks again +1. Do note that I'm using just the `Intent` part from this with a screenshot bitmap.

Comment: in whatsapp i'm getting error  "Sharing failed, please try again."

Comment: Chooser is showing duplicate Apps like FB messenger and FB messenger 'Your Story'

Comment: you, dear sir, is a life savour and the massiah himself in blood and flesh

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70938272/12781179

Answer (score 20):

please have a look on this code worked for me to share an text and image together

```
Intent shareIntent;
    Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+"/Share.png";
    OutputStream out = null;
    File file=new File(path);
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    path=file.getPath();
    Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse("file://"+path);
    shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Hey please check this application " + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" +getPackageName());
    shareIntent.setType("image/png");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share with"));
```

Don't forget to give WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE Permission

also in facebook it can only share the image because facebook is not allowing to share the text via intent

Comment: This is the best answer so far, and the only one which is working for me all the others are not.

Comment: best answer. in this page

Comment: Chooser is showing duplicate Apps like FB messenger and FB messenger 'Your Story'

Comment: Unfortunately, on Viber it's only sharing the image, not the text.

Comment: to share mage using public folder and write permission, you can use app personal folders

Answer (score 6):

It is possibly because the sharing app (FB, twitter, etc) may not have permissions to read the image.

Google's document says:

> The receiving application needs permission to access the data the Uri points to. The recommended ways to do this are:

http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

I am not sure the sharing apps have permissions to read an image in the bundle of our apps. But my files saved in

```
 Activity.getFilesDir()
```

***cannot*** be read. As suggested in the above link, we may consider to store images in the MediaStore, where the sharing apps have permissions to read.

**Update1:**
The following is working code to share image with text in Android 4.4.

```
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath());
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Constant.SHARE_MESSAGE
            + Constant.SHARE_URL);
        String url= MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(this.getContentResolver(), bm, "title", "description");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image"));
```

The side effect is we add an image in the MediaStore.

Comment: If the share is finished, you can simply remove the image from MediaStore and nothing happend ;-)

Comment: Chooser is showing duplicate Apps like FB messenger and FB messenger 'Your Story'

Answer (score 4):

try using this code.I am uploading ic_launcher from drawable.you can change this with your file from gallary or bitmap.

```
void share() {
    Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/jpeg");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hello #test");

    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
            Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/temporary_file.jpg"));            
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
}
```

Comment: Chooser is showing duplicate Apps like FB messenger and FB messenger 'Your Story'

Comment: @AmanVerma FB Story and FB Messenger are definitely two different things.

Answer (score 4):

I have been looking for solution of this question for a while and found this one up and running, hope it helps.

```
private BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable;
private Bitmap bitmap1;
//write this code in your share button or function

bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) mImageView.getDrawable();// get the from imageview or use your drawable from drawable folder
bitmap1 = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
String imgBitmapPath= MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),bitmap1,"title",null);
Uri imgBitmapUri=Uri.parse(imgBitmapPath);
String shareText="Share image and text";
Intent shareIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("*/*");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,imgBitmapUri);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareText);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share Wallpaper using"));
```

Comment: Chooser is showing duplicate Apps like FB messenger and FB messenger 'Your Story'

Answer (score 4):

```
 String bitmapPath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, "title", null);
        Uri bitmapUri = Uri.parse(bitmapPath);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/png");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bitmapUri);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is a playstore link to download.. " + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName());

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share"));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String text = "Look at my awesome picture";
Uri pictureUri = Uri.parse("file://my_picture");
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share images..."));
```

Comment: Chooser is showing duplicate Apps like FB messenger and FB messenger 'Your Story'

Answer (score 2):

Check the below code it worked for me

```
    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load("image url path").into(new Target() {

           @Override

            public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Let me recommend you this application" +
                        "\n"+ "your share url or text ");
                i.setType("image/*");
                i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getLocalBitmapUri(bitmap));
                context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share using"));
            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
            }
        });


     private Uri getLocalBitmapUri(Bitmap bmp) {
      Uri bmpUri = null;
      try {
          File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "share_image_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, out);
        out.close();
        bmpUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bmpUri;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void shareImage(){

    StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());

    Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.Starlay_straightface_image);


    File f =  new File(getExternalCacheDir()+"/"+getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)+".png");
    Intent shareIntent;


    try {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,outputStream);

        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(f));
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Hey please check this application " + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" +getPackageName());
        shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);


    }catch (Exception e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share Picture"));
}
```

Comment: pay attention to StrictMode.setVmPolicy, it's required to avoid crash

Answer (score 1):

To share a drawable image, the image has to be first saved in device's cache or external storage.

We check if "sharable_image.jpg" already exists in cache, if exists, the path is retrieved from existing file.

Else, the drawable image is saved in cache.

The saved image is then shared using intent.

```
private void share() {
    int sharableImage = R.drawable.person2;
    Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), sharableImage);
    String path = getExternalCacheDir()+"/sharable_image.jpg";
    java.io.OutputStream out;
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File(path);

    if(!file.exists()) {
        try {
            out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    path = file.getPath();

    Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse("file://" + path);

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is a sample body with more detailed description");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share with"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20333318/8821876) solution with Android X and works perfectly with whatsapp, telegram and gmail.
This is my code:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "<<sharingText>>");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("<<imageResource>>"));
shareIntent.setType("image/*");
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); 
if (getView() != null && getView().getContext() != null &&       
    shareIntent.resolveActivity(getView().getContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {                 
    getView().getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, null));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By accident(the text message part, I had given up on that), I noticed that when I chose Messages App to handle the request, the Message App would open with the text from Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT plus the image ready to send, I hope it helps.

```
String[] recipient = {"your_email_here"};
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipient);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Hello, this is the subject line");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, messageEditText.getText().toString());
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
intent.setType("image/*");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can this code it is working

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.refer_image);
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/*" + "text/*");
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(this.getContentResolver(),
            b, "Title", null);
    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(path);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hey I am Subhajit");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share via"));
```

Answer (score 0):

File Provider:

it is good to use FileProvider to share image to other app securely.
it work on all version of android.

i tried it and works fine.

Link:
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider

Answer (score 0):

#### Here How to Share Image + Text together using ACTION_SEND in android

1. create a temporary file to store your image

   ```
    File cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
    File file = new File(cacheDir, "my_image.png");  // give any name to your temp file with suffix same as your image file (.png)
    file.deleteOnExit();  // this will delete your temp file on teminate
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
   ```
2. create bitmap for your drawable and store it in your file

   ```
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_abc); // your image name without suffix
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);  // remember to use the same format as your image type (PNG)
    fos.close();
   ```
3. fetch uri from your temp file

   ```
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "in.abc.def.fileProvider", file); 
    // where "in.abc.def.fileProvider" is the name of the authorities for your provider which is defined in AndroidManifest.xml
   ```

dummy reference for AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="in.abc.def.fileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

4. create an intent to send text and image

   ```
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setType("image/*");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "some text");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    Intent shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null);
    activity.startActivity(shareIntent);
   ```