# How to Share Image+Text using Share Intent in android

Tags: android

I use this code, but its not working properly.

```
String Body = "Deals Name: " + Bussinessname + "\n"
    + "Deals: " + deal + "\n" + "Address: " + city
    + " ," + country;

Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

Uri screenshotUri = Uri.parse(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI + "/" + image);
share.setType("image/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "The EssexPass");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Body);
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, screenshotUri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Deal"));
```

When I use the type text, then it works properly.
But I want to share a text and an image.
And the share intent is not working in FaceBook.

Comment: Yes it will not work with facebook because facebook's policy as it says that `API does not support pre-filling the message for users`

Comment: You need to use Facebook SDK to do that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Share Image + Text together using ACTION\_SEND in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333186/how-to-share-image-text-together-using-action-send-in-android)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try out the below code:

```
String fileName = "image-3116.jpg";//Name of an image
String externalStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
String myDir = externalStorageDirectory + "/saved_images/"; // the file will be in saved_images
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///" + myDir + fileName);
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/html");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Test Mail");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Launcher");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Deal"));
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the type and action ? @HardikParmar

Comment: i not get any error but when i click on gmail that time to gmail is force close and in what's up its not send your text like that

Comment: sorry its working but not the proper way in gmail its image is not load. and whats up is not show, and in hike only image uploaded ...

Comment: I do not see Facebook as provider when chooser starts

Answer (score 2):

Using intent filter we are not able to share the both text + image on facebook. If you want to share the image and text together then you have to create the bitmap of image + text.

Download the source code here([Share image and text on facebook using intent in android](https://deepshikhapuri.wordpress.com/2016/12/12/share-image-and-text-on-facebook-using-intent-in-android/))

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.shareimage;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    EditText et_text;
    ImageView iv_image;
    TextView tv_share,tv_text;
    RelativeLayout rl_main;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();

    }

    private void init(){
        et_text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_text);
        iv_image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_image);
        tv_share = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_share);
        rl_main = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl_main);
        tv_text= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_text);

        File dir = new File("/sdcard/Testing/");
        try {
            if (dir.mkdir()) {
                System.out.println("Directory created");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Directory is not created");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        tv_share.setOnClickListener(this);

        et_text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                tv_text.setText(et_text.getText().toString());

            }
        });


    }




    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.tv_share:
                Bitmap bitmap1 = loadBitmapFromView(rl_main, rl_main.getWidth(), rl_main.getHeight());
                saveBitmap(bitmap1);
                String str_screenshot = "/sdcard/Testing/"+"testing" + ".jpg";

                fn_share(str_screenshot);
                break;
        }

    }

    public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        File imagePath = new File("/sdcard/Testing/"+"testing" + ".jpg");
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();

            Log.e("ImageSave", "Saveimage");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v, int width, int height) {
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        v.draw(c);

        return b;
    }

    public void fn_share(String path) {

        File file = new File("/mnt/" + path);

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Image"));


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read sharing binary content on [Android Dev](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html#send-binary-content),

Sample code

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriToImage);
shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
```

Comment: you haven't noticed `uriToImage`, it is the path of the image you want to send.

Comment: What about the drawable image and image url ?
How can we share it ?

Comment: Explain what do you mean by `drawable image` and `image url`

Answer (score 1):

You need to put extra in intent:

```
intent.putExtra("extra_name_1", ”some value”);
intent.putExtra("extra_name_2", 123);
intent.putExtra("extra_name_3”, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi  First u need to add  `compile com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0` in your build gradle and then follow this link.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.3

Answer (score -1):

If you want to **share image from url**
and **text** with it using **intent**
use following block in your share method

for **Java**:

```
AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           try {
               URL url = new URL("Your url here");
               HttpURLConnection connection = null;
               connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
               connection.connect();
               InputStream inputStream = null;
               inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
               Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
               Bitmap b = myBitmap;
               Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
               share.setType("Image/jpeg");
               share.setType("text/html");
               share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "shre body");
               ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
               b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
               String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(MainActivity.getContentResolver(), b, "Title", null);
               Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(path);
               share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
               MainActivity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Select"));
           }
           catch (Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
    });
```

and in **kotlin** :

```
  AsyncTask.execute {
                try {
                    val url = URL("Your url here")
                    var connection: HttpURLConnection? = null
                    connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection?
                    connection!!.connect()
                    var inputStream: InputStream? = null
                    inputStream = connection.inputStream
                    val myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
                    val share = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                    share.type = "Image/jpeg"
                    share.type = "text/html"
                    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text message here")
                    val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                    myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes)
                    val path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                        activity?.getContentResolver(),
                        myBitmap,
                        "Title",
                        null
                    )
                    val imageUri = Uri.parse(path)
                    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri)
                    activity?.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Select"))
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                }

            }
```

In my journey of had the same problem at that time i use this
thanks you