# How do create whatsapp share option in my app

Tags: android, share-intent

I am new to Android development. I don't know Android Studio and Java. But I am developing an app with the help of Google, YouTube and StackOverflow. Now I want to add share option (Image + text) in my `Recyclerview` image to Whatsapp.

The image is loaded from `Firebase` storage using `Picasso` lib. I don't know how to convert `Firebase ImageView` to `bitmap`.

I have added a Share button below each item. How do I create share option in this sharebutton?

This is my MainActivity:

```
public class ReviewMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String APP_ID = "ca-app-pub-8867939169855032~3069406037";

    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference MCR;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ReviewModel, ReviewViewHolder> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_review_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.ReviewMain_Toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
        toolbar.setLogo(R.mipmap.uploadpost);
        toolbar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(ReviewMainActivity.this, ReviewPostUploadActivity.class);
                startActivity(settingsIntent);
            }
        });

        if (getSupportActionBar()!=null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }

        MobileAds.initialize(this,APP_ID);
        AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        MCR = database.getReference("Review");

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_ReviewMain);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager (layoutManager);

        loadMenu();
    }

    private void loadMenu() {
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ReviewModel, ReviewViewHolder>(ReviewModel.class,
                R.layout.review_main_items,
                ReviewViewHolder.class,MCR) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(ReviewViewHolder viewHolder, ReviewModel model, final int position) {
                viewHolder.Review_Title.setText(model.getTitle());
                viewHolder.Profile_Name.setText(model.getProfileName());

                Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getImage())
                        .into(viewHolder.Review_Image);

                Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(model.getProfileimage())
                        .into(viewHolder.Profile_Image);

                final ReviewModel local = model;

                viewHolder.Share_Icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home)
            finish();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is my Intent Part

```
Intent shareIntent;
Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+"/Share.png";
OutputStream out = null;
File file=new File(path);
try {
    out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
path=file.getPath();
Uri bmpUri = Uri.parse("file://"+path);
shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bmpUri);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Hey please check this application " + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" +getPackageName());
shareIntent.setType("image/png");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Share with"));
```

Comment: So you want to share image/ text/ or (image+text)?

Comment: oh sorry i want share image+text

Comment: Go ahead and try this Dharmesh rughani's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333186/how-to-share-image-text-together-using-action-send-in-android . Let me know if you still find it difficult.

Comment: just tried but image didnt load in share option. My imageview load from Firebase. how to convert imageview in to bitmap.

Comment: can you try:
    `try {
        URL url = new URL("http://....");
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }`

Comment: message send faild in whatsapp. cant attach empty file in gmail

Comment: Can you add your code (just the intent share part) in the question?

Comment: Intent part added

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Intent uriIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("whatsapp://send?text=" + "Text you want to share"));
startActivity(uriIntent);
```

This will open whatsapp and will ask you for the people you want to send the entered text to.

To send a file do this

```
  File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "example.pdf");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(outputFile);

Intent share = new Intent();
share.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("application/pdf");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
share.setPackage("com.whatsapp");

activity.startActivity(share);
```

The above code will send pdf files.

To send the image (one image) , replace “application/pdf” with “image/*”

Remember : application will crash if you try to send text, pdf and image all at the same time, so send only one item at a time.

Comment: Thanks brother. Text sharing working perfectly. but i want to share image also. how to send image.

Comment: Also added for the image