# How can I tweet texts and images from an Android App in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, twitter

#### What I would like to do

I would like to tweet text and image from an Android App.

I was able to put an image to tweet on a screen of app and the app can open tweet form via a button.

As a reference, I checked the following former question.

[How to Share Image + Text together using ACTION_SEND in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333186/how-to-share-image-text-together-using-action-send-in-android)

#### Problem

Problem is set text and image data on the program are not appeared to the twitter.

It only show blank tweet form.

How can I move these text and image from the Android app to the tweet form?

#### Code

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.tweets

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.util.Log
import androidx.core.app.ShareCompat
import java.io.File
import android.R.attr.path
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import androidx.core.app.ComponentActivity.ExtraData
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getSystemService
import android.icu.lang.UCharacter.GraphemeClusterBreak.T
import java.io.IOException


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        try {resources.assets.open("sample.jpg").use { istream ->
            val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istream)
            sample.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }


        val intentTweetButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.intentTweetButton)
        intentTweetButton.setOnClickListener {
            shareTwitter()
        }

        /*

        val shareCompatButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.shareCompatButton)
        shareCompatButton.setOnClickListener {
            shareCompat()
        }
        */
    }

    fun shareTwitter() {
        val message = "shareTwitter intent tweet"
        val bmpUri = Uri.parse("file://$path")
        try {
            val sharingIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            sharingIntent.setClassName("com.twitter.android", "com.twitter.android.PostActivity")
            val imageUri = Uri.parse("sample.jpg")
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello")
            sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri)
            sharingIntent.type = "image/jpeg"
            sharingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            startActivity(sharingIntent)
        }
        catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("In Exception", "Comes here")
            val i = Intent()
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message)
            i.action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
            i.data = Uri.parse("https://mobile.twitter.com/compose/tweet")
            startActivity(i)
        }

    }

    /*

    fun shareCompat() {
        val message = "shareCompat"
        val builder = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
        builder.setChooserTitle("Choose App")
        builder.setText(message)
        builder.setType("text/plain")
        builder.addStream(Uri.fromFile(File("sample.jpg")))
        builder.setType("image/jpg")
        builder.startChooser()
    }
     */
}
```

activity_main.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sample"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/img_description"
        tools:ignore="InvalidId" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/intentTweetButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="intent tweet"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <!--
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/shareCompatButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="ShareCompat"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/intentTweetButton" />
     -->

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

#### What I tried to do

I tried to use `share compat` instead of `intent`, but it didn't work neither.

In addition to that,  `share compat` is only available for user who have downloaded Twitter app on the phones, so I prefer to use `intent` to tweet text and image from the Android app.

The image is located on `app/assets/sample.jpg`.

#### Environment

Android Studio 3.5.3

Kotlin plugin 1.3.50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 private void shareTwitter(String message) {
    Intent tweetIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    tweetIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is a Test.");
    tweetIntent.setType("text/plain");

    PackageManager packManager = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> resolvedInfoList = packManager.queryIntentActivities(tweetIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

    boolean resolved = false;
    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resolvedInfoList) {
        if (resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName.startsWith("com.twitter.android")) {
            tweetIntent.setClassName(
                    resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName,
                    resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);
            resolved = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (resolved) {
        startActivity(tweetIntent);
    } else {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + urlEncode(message)));
        startActivity(i);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Twitter app isn't found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private String urlEncode(String s) {
    try {
        return URLEncoder.encode(s, "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.wtf(TAG, "UTF-8 should always be supported", e);
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have converted you code to Kotlin, but a couple of errors appeared. I have added my current situations to the my question and it is appreciated if you could let me know your opinion.

Comment: It is helpful whether the location where I added your solution is correct or not.

Comment: you can try "https://try.kotlinlang.org/" website to convert your java code to kotlin.