# Is there a way to share image with text in .net maui?

Tags: c#, android, ios, maui

I want to share image **with** text to external programs (such as Telegram, Instagram, etc.). IShare offers two options: **only** image/images, or **only** text. Platforms: android and ios.

I googled for it, but found nothing. Also nothing suggestive in public api.

Answer (score 0):

The MAUI documents do mention a `Subject` property on `ShareTextRequest` here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.applicationmodel.datatransfer.sharetextrequest?view=net-maui-7.0

Otherwise, you may be able to use the `Title` property on `ShareRequestBase`:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.applicationmodel.datatransfer.sharerequestbase.title?view=net-maui-7.0

For Android specifically it appears that you can use `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` for this purpose, as this answer suggests: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20333318/2147110

Comment: As i said, there is no possibillity to send image and text via one share provider in net maui public apis. Looks like the only way is to create own platform specific implementaion for this purpose for Android and ios.